# agarrar con auth el id del negocio con el que estoy logueada

Tags: php

Hola gente estoy tratando de agarrar con auth el id del negocio con el que estoy logueada y me trae el id del usuario con el que estoy logueada, ese usuario tiene un negocio y yo quiero que me traiga el id del negocio

Comment: Trabajas php puro?

Comment: si , gracias mau voy a probar =)

Comment: Tu pregunta lleva dos votos de cierre, deberías checar [ask]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que inicias sesión (consulta y creación de variables), así como la estructura de las tablas involucradas o, al menos los datos de relación entre ellas.

Answer (score 0):

podrías intentar algo así:

$cu=wp_get_current_user();
$conn = New PDO("mysql: host=$servername; dbname=$database;","$username","$password");
if(is_user_loggedin(){
global $cu
$reg = "select registro from wp_user where id=".$cu->ID;
$reg2 = $conn->query($reg);
while ($reg[0]==
}

Comment: Un código sin mayor contexto no resulta de mucha aplicabilidad como sabes que usa pdo? Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Sin contar detalles como global o is_user_loggedin por favor si la pregunta es mala no dejemos que la respuesta también lo sea